# How do I compartmentalize classes in objective-c w/o namespaces?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

Having worked w/ languages that utilized namespaces for the past 10 years I am trying to figure out the best approach to project structure and class names in  objective-c (iOS4+). Should you simply give all your classes, view controllers, etc. unique names? It seems archaic there is not a way to encapsulate groups of functionality with something like namespaces, especially if you build libraries and have a large development team.

Is there functionality equivalent to namespaces that I am missing? If not, what is a good approach to this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for asking. I am working in .Net and I missed the namespaces too for huge project in objective-c XCode. I found the "namespaces" class in "snipped library" but I think its not the same?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Should you simply give all your classes, view controllers, etc. unique names?

Yes.

Answer (score 3):

The standard approach is to prefix class names with a short code. For instance, traditional Cocoa uses `NS` (from NextStep), while Cocoa Touch uses `UI` (for user interface, I guess).